# Behavioral biomarkers in transgender people (or animals)?

Tags: neuropsychology, transgenderism, behavioral-psychology, behavioral-biology

I just randomly heard this soundbyte that was saying that women are more inclined to kleptomania and men pyromania. This was in the context of an anger management course, so it was implied they are perhaps compulsive behaviors that arise out of a lack of self-control or spurred by negative feelings including the aftermath of anger.

I think there was some kind of claimed biological reason for this, say, something hormonal, or maybe related to brain structure.

I was just curious, the extent to which “gender” may actually have some very deep biological-behavioral aspects, has there ever been any research done on observing that transgender people may exhibit some of those biological-behavioral characteristics of their previous/original gender?

I also include animals because someone told me some animals exhibit transgenderism.